# Speed up bash script converting git repo to LFS

Tags: git, bash, shell, sed, git-lfs

I am trying to convert a git repository to lfs. I am trying out this bash script at the moment and noticed that its pretty slow. Does anyone know how to speed this up a bit ? I am not realy in this whole bash thing.

```
git filter-branch --prune-empty --tree-filter '
git lfs track "*.psd"
git lfs track "*.jpg"
git lfs track "*.png"
git add .gitattributes 
git ls-files -z | xargs -0 git check-attr filter | grep "filter: lfs" | sed -E "s/(.*): filter: lfs/\1/" | tr "\n" "\0" | while read -r -d $'"'\0'"' file; do
    echo "Processing ${file}"
    git rm -f --cached "${file}"
    echo "Adding $file lfs style"
    git add "${file}"
done
' --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

Comment: @Thomas thanks for editing the code, looks better now. Sorry if i did something wrong, im new here. Im happy about every help.

Comment: One quick note -- you're better off running one `git rm -f` and one `git add` with a bunch of filenames on each, rather than running each command once per file.

Comment: ...and the `tr` is silly: If you already have newlines, you aren't making things any better/safer by changing them to NULs before going to read

Comment: ...and you **can't** have a literal NUL in a C-style string, which is what bash uses, so your use of `read -d` doesn't behave quite the way you expect it to. Just `IFS= read -r -d ''` suffices to read a NUL-delimited string: The first character of a string is used, and the first character of a C-style empty string is NUL. (`-r` prevents literal backslashes from being munged, and `IFS=` prevents trailing whitespace from being removed).

Comment: Also, instead of `grep | sed`, I'd consider using a single awk command to do the job of both -- less potential for impedance mismatch between your pipeline stages to result in trouble that way anyhow.

Comment: ...all that said, chances are good that most of your overhead is being spent inside `git lfs`, not in bash, so asking for bash optimizations may not be much help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider replacing

```
while read -r -d $'"'\0'"' file; do
    echo "Processing ${file}"
    git rm -f --cached "${file}"
    echo "Adding $file lfs style"
    git add "${file}"
done
```

with...

```
xargs -0 sh -c '
  printf "Processing file: %s\n" "$@"
  git rm -f --cached "$@" && git add "$@"
' _
```

That way, instead of invoking `git rm` and `git add` once per file, you invoke both tools only a single time for each group of files up to the maximum size that will fit in the available space shared between your environment variables and command-line length.

---

I would also suggest combining your `git lfs track` commands into a single invocation. For instance, if you read [the source to the `track` command,](https://github.com/github/git-lfs/blob/master/commands/command_track.go) you'll see that it supports the following usage:

```
git lfs track "*.psd" "*.jpg" "*.png"
```

Comment: Okay, thanks for the reply. I will try it tomorrow, and give you some more feedback about the saved time. I appreciate your help alot.